# getopt ordering function in C

Tags: c, beginner

I was writing a program and I needed a function that could ordinate the `argv` according to my preferences.  That way, `getopt` would parse the options as needed.  I couldn't find any, so I wrote one.  I would be very thankful if you guys could have a look and say what you think about it.  I'm a C beginner, so don't save comments; I really want to learn!

usage: include the header and use the function like this:

...

```
/* before the getopt function */
ordering(l:ds:k:w);
/* so l will be parsed first, d second, s third...*/
```

...

[git repo to the function](https://github.com/paolocarrara/getopt_ordering)

Two files(_getopt.h and ordering.c):

The first one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **ordering (int *, char **, char *);
```

And, the second one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0

/* returns the size of a given line */
int get_line_size (char *line) {

    return strlen (line);
}

/* returns TRUE if argv[0] is an option, else, returns FALSE */
int verify_if_is_option (char *argv) {

    if (argv != NULL) {
        if (argv[0] == '-') {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

/* counts the number of progem in the given argv
 * problem def.: a problem is when a we have option and
 * its argument together, like this: -vbike
 * this kind of problem need to be treated, to the rest of
 * the functions work properly
 * */
int problem_counter (int argc, char **argv) {
    int i;
    int number_of_problens;

    for (i = 1, number_of_problens = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        if (verify_if_is_option (argv[i]) == TRUE) {
            if (get_line_size (argv[i]) > 2) {
                number_of_problens++;
            }
        }
    }

    return number_of_problens;
}

/* the orignal argv coudn't be modified, it's reallocced 
 * notice: the functions doesn't really reallocs the the argv,
 * it just creates another matrix with more size - for the additional
 * lines - and copy everithing from the original one.
 * */
char **malloc_argv (int argc, char **argv, int t_problens) {

    char **new;
    int i;

    new = malloc ((argc+t_problens)*sizeof(char*));

    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        new[i] = argv[i];
    }

    for (; i < argc + t_problens; i++) {
        new[i] = NULL;
    }

    return new;
}

/* find and return a problematic line
 * problematic line def.: a problematic lines is a line whose
 * its option and argument are together in the same vector of the
 * matrix
 * */

char *get_problematic_line (int argc, char **argv) {

    int i;
    char *line;

    line = NULL;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (verify_if_is_option (argv[i]) == TRUE) {
            if (get_line_size (argv[i]) > 2) {
                line = argv[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return line;
}

/* get and return the argument of a given line */
char *get_argument (char *line) {

    char *argument;
    int i;

    argument = malloc ((strlen(line)-1)*sizeof(char));

    for (i = 2; i < strlen(line); i++) {
        argument[i-2] = line[i];
    }
    argument[i-2] = '\0';

    return argument;
}

/* push down all the lines from the i element to the bottom */
char **push_down (int argc, char **argv, int i) {

    for (; argc > i+1; argc--) {
        argv[argc-1] = argv[argc-2];
    }

    return argv;
}

/* just do what it name says */
char **push_one_line_down_from_here (char *line, int argc, char **argv) {

    int i;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (argv[i] == line) {
            argv = push_down (argc, argv, i);
            i = argc;
        }
    }

    return argv;
}

/* just do what it name says */
char **insert_argument_below_this_line (char *line, char *argument, char **argv) {

    int i;

    for (i = 1; line != argv[i]; i++);  
    argv[i+1] = argument;

    return argv;
}

/* to remove the argument from a problematic line
 * this function puts a '\0' at where the option should end
 * */
void remove_argument_from_problematic_line (char *line) {

    line[2] = '\0';
}

/* realloc the argv matrix and identify and separate problematic lines
 * obs.: problematic lines are defined in the get_problematic_line function
 * */
char **malloc_and_divide (int *argc, char **argv) {

    int t_problens;
    char *line;
    char *argument;

    t_problens = problem_counter (*argc, argv);

    argv = malloc_argv (*argc, argv, t_problens);

    (*argc) +=t_problens;

    for (;t_problens > 0; t_problens--) {
        line = get_problematic_line (*argc, argv);
        argument = get_argument (line);
        argv = push_one_line_down_from_here (line, *argc, argv);
        argv = insert_argument_below_this_line (line, argument, argv);
        remove_argument_from_problematic_line(line);
    }

    return argv;
}

/**** THIS PIECE OF CODE IS FOR THE SECOND PART OF THE FUCNTION ****/

/* 'transform' a litteral string in a mallocced string */
char *litteral_to_dinamic (char *literal) {

    int i;
    char *dinamic = malloc ((strlen(literal)+1)*sizeof(char));

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(literal); i++) {
        dinamic[i] = literal[i];
    }
    dinamic[i] = '\0';

    return dinamic;
}

/* returns the next option in optstring */
char get_desired_option (char *optstring) {

/*char option = optstring[0];
return option; */
    return optstring[0];
}

/* remove an already used option in optstring */
void remove_option_used (char *optstring) {

    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= strlen(optstring); i++) {
        optstring[i-1] = optstring[i];
    }

    if (optstring[0] == ':') {
        remove_option_used (optstring);
    }
}

/* returns true if the desired option is in argv, if it is, this
 * option will be replaced in the right place, else, nothing will
 * be done
 * */
int is_in_argv (int argc, char **argv, char option) {

    int i;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (argv[i][0] == '-' && argv[i][1] == option) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}

/* returns true if both the option that need to be replaced and the
 * option that is in the 'wrong' place have an argument
 * */
int both_have_argument (int argc, char **argv, int position, int i) {

    if(i < argc-1) {
        if((argv[position+1][0] != '-') && (argv[i+1][0] != '-')) {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

/* just do what it name says */
void change_both_arguments (int argc, char **argv, int position, int i) {

    char *aux;

    aux = argv[position+1];
    argv[position+1] = argv[i+1];
    argv[i+1] = aux;
}

/* return true if only the first option have an argument
 * the first option is the not desired option
 * */
int first_have_argument (int argc, char **argv, int position) {

    if (position < argc-1) {
        if (argv[position+1][0] != '-') {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}

/* just do what it name says */
void change_first_argument (int argc, char **argv, int position, int i) {

    char *aux;

    aux = argv[position+1];

    for (position++; position < i; position++) {
        argv[position] = argv[position+1];
    }
    argv[i] = aux;
}

/* return true if only the second option have an argument
 * the second option the desired option
 * */
int second_have_argument (int argc, char **argv, int i) {

    if (i < argc-1) {
        if (argv[i+1][0] != '-') {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}

/* just do what it name says */
void change_second_argument (int argc, char **argv, int position, int i) {

    char *aux;
    int j;

    aux = argv[i+1];

    for (j = i+1; j > position; j--) {
        argv[j] = argv[j-1];
    }
    argv[position+1] = aux;
}

/* returns the next position that a desired option will fit */
int verify_arguments (int argc, char **argv, int position, int i) {

    if (both_have_argument (argc, argv, position, i) == TRUE) {
        change_both_arguments (argc, argv, position, i);
        return position+2;
}
    else if (first_have_argument (argc, argv, position) == TRUE) {
        change_first_argument (argc, argv, position, i);
        return position+1;
    }
    else if (second_have_argument (argc, argv, i) == TRUE) {
        change_second_argument (argc, argv, position, i);
        return position+2;
}
    else 
        return position+1;
}


/* changes the option position that is in optstring and was found in the argv */
int change_option_position (int argc, char **argv, char option, int position) {

    int i;
    char *aux;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (argv[i][0] == '-' && argv[i][1] == option) {
            aux = argv[position];
            argv[position] = argv[i];
            argv[i] = aux;
            position = verify_arguments (argc, argv, position, i);
        }
    }

    return position;
}

/* organizes the argv according to the optstring requirents */
char **organize (int argc, char **argv, char *optstring) {

    int position;
    char option;

    position = 1;

    optstring = litteral_to_dinamic (optstring);

    while (optstring[0] != '\0') {
        option = get_desired_option (optstring);
        remove_option_used (optstring);
        if ((is_in_argv(argc, argv, option)) ==  TRUE) {
            position = change_option_position (argc, argv, option, position);
        }

    }

    return argv;
}

/**** THE MAIN CALLER ****/

/* the main function */
char **ordering (int *argc, char **argv, char *optstring) {

    argv = malloc_and_divide (argc, argv);

    argv = organize (*argc, argv, optstring);

    return argv;
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling you have written some stuff that solves a non-existent problem.  As far as I know, other people manage fine with `getopt` etc, so what is it about your eventual program that needs this arg-list reordering?  Can you explain a bit more what you need to achieve and why?

Comment: I'm writing a program that needed the -l option to be parsed before the -c option. -l says the says the size of the password, the -c says what type of character use to create the password: something like this: ./plist -l5 -c[alpha]    if the -c option was parsed first so when it expand the length of the password it will have portions of it that wasn't initialized.

Comment: If you want to see the program that I'm writing, just look in the plist repo. The code IS NOT done!! So, errors can happen, and if you want to advice me about anything, please say! I will be very glad!

Comment: So is "alpha" the password in this example? Why would you need to announce how long it is when it it there in the string?  And if that really is not enough, why can't you just set some flags as you parse the arg list and then do the processing when you know what you have? Maybe I'll look at your program as you suggest...

Comment: The password is a not fixed string. It will be generated by the program. I need to say what is the length of the passwords that will be generate using the char set specified. example: ./plist -l3 -c[digit] will output: 000 001 002 003...997 998 999. So, if the -c options comes first, the *password pointer will have no length at all, because wasn't had any malloc(l*sizeof(char)), got it? About the flags, how this works? I mean, I think that I know what is a flag, but how to use it in this case. If you could take a look at plist would be great! \o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than continue in the comments, I talk here. This isn't a review of the code...

As I wrote above, I think you have written some stuff that solves a non-existent problem. As far as I know, other people manage fine with getopt etc.

As far as I can see, the following code extracted from your project and altered, does what you need without reordering the argument list:

```
void get_opt (int argc, char **argv, passSettings *pass)
{
    int option;
    int length = 0;
    char *cset = NULL;
    char *pos = NULL;
    char *output = NULL;

    while ((option = getopt(argc, argv, "l:o:k:c:hv")) != -1)
        switch (option) {
            case 'l': length = strtol(optarg, 0, 0); break;
            case 'o': output = optarg; break;
            case 'c': cset = optarg; break;
            case 'k': pos = optarg; break;
            case 'v': version (); break;
            case 'h':
            default: help (); break;
        }
    setPasswordsLength(length, pass);
    setOutput(output, pass);
    setCharacterSet(cset, pass);
    setCharsPositions(pos, pass);
    if (getfp (pass) != NULL) printPasswordSetConfiguration (pass);
}
```

Clearly you might need some error handling in there or in the called functions, but I've shown the basic idea.  Of course I might have a completely wrong understanding of what you want...

---

**EDIT** : as requested as few comments.  These are comments on the code, concentrating on the style and some details and ignoring the logic.

- `get_line_size` is redundant - just use `strlen`
- `verify_if_is_option` is verbose.  The following does the same.  Note also
  the use of `const` on the pointer parameter because the data pointed to is not
  changed by the function.

  ```
  int verify_if_is_option (const char *argv)
  {
      return (argv && (argv[0] == '-'));
  }
  ```

  I have not used TRUE/FALSE as these are not really necessary in C.  The
  function returns the result of the expression: 1 if it is true, 0
  otherwise.  When you call the function you would do:

  ```
  if (verify_if_is_option (argv[i])) {
  ```

  This would read better if the function were named just `is_option`
- The control variable in `for` loops can often be defined within the loop:

  ```
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
  ```

  Note that the scope of `i` above is only the loop, so if you want to use
  the resulting value on termination of the loop, you must define the
  variable outside the loop.
- It is generally better to define and initialise a variable at the point of
  first use, for example in `malloc_argv`:

  ```
  char **new = malloc(argc + t_problens);
  ```

  Note that I didn't use `sizeof(char)` because that is 1 by definition.
  Also note the spacing.  It is generally best to check `malloc` (etc)
  for failure.  Often the only thing that can be done is to print an
  error and exit, but that is better than seg-faulting on the NULL
  pointer returned by a failed `malloc` call.
- `get_argument` (and `litteral_to_dinamic`) is verbose.  You can just use
  `strdup` if you have it or write your own:

  ```
  char* strdup(const char *s)
  {
      size_t len = strlen(s);
      char *t = malloc(len + 1);
      if (t != NULL) {
          memcpy(t, s, len + 1);
      }
      return t;
  }
  ```

  Note `s` is `const`, the length is taken once and then used in the
  malloc and `memcpy` calls (you already have the length so you can use
  the more efficient `memcpy` instead of `strcpy`).  To duplicate just
  part of the string, pass the relevant offset, eg:

  ```
  char *copy = strdup(line + 2);
  ```
- Empty loops are better made explicit - it is easy to miss a semicolon at
  the end of the `for` statement:

  ```
  for (i = 1; line != argv[i]; i++) { /*nothing*/ }
  ```
- Putting a call to `strlen` inside a loop where the argument does not
  change, as in

  ```
  for (i = 1; i <= strlen(optstring); i++) {
  ```

  is arguably lazy/wrong.  If compiler optimizations are enabled, the
  compiler will probably remove the `strlen` call from the loop.  All the
  same, I prefer to see it explicit:

  ```
  const size_t len = strlen(optstring);

  for (size_t i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
  ```

Comment: You just made me sad... Yes! The flags! How could I be so... Well, even though the flags can solve my problem they introduce new variables that I will have to be worry, I know! this is nothing compared to the job in writing a function to handle it. But, I'm really thankful for your help. Any other observation will be very appreciated.

Comment: The variables are local to the get_opt function aren't they? In that case they are not a cause of worry.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'm going to review my code to make it more inteligent. Again, thanks a lot for your observations and corrections.